# ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!vault' by using the C based SafeLoader

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to read a YAML file using ruamel.yaml that has the tag !vault in it. I get the error : **could not determine a constructor for the tag '!vault'**
The reason why I'm using ruamel.yaml to prevent quotes in yaml structure and I want to use safe typ because of performance.  I understood that I need to generate a constructor to resolve this issue, but I could not find any instruction how to do it.

```py
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe', pure=False)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.explicit_start = True
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)

sfile="boot.yaml"
with open(sfile, 'r') as stream:
   data = yaml.load(stream)
print(data)
```

The YAML file I am using:

```yaml
---
level1:
  bootstrap:
    user: admin
    admin_user: "yes"
    admin_password: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      23423423423423423423423423423443336133616235373030363166616533396264363132323038
      31393636333735316430633062326638616665383865643453453453453453453453453453453465
      34333265303537643831376238366437336265363134396632613931376265623338346464663964
      3932653961633536360a653466383734653433313135393530323063663034373663363936306264
      30613762613164396539653462343437234234234234234234234346547567556345645763534534
```

the error is:

```
data = constructor(self, node)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 690, in construct_undefined
    raise ConstructorError(
ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!vault'
  in "boot.yaml", line 6, column 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html) describes how to dump (`to_yaml` method) and load (`from_yaml` method) So you can e.g. make a class `Vault` and provide a `from_yaml` classmethod that constructs a `Vault` instance.

`yaml.preservequotes` doesn't do anything when your not using a round-trip (default) YAML instance.

The more important question is though, how many megabytes is your YAML file, that you downgrade to the C loader, with still many of the bugs, incompatibilities and idiosyncrasies from the orginal `libyaml`.

---

In practise, if you have just one tag to deal with you can do (assuming your input is in the file `input.yaml`):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

    
file_in = Path('input.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

@yaml.register_class
class Vault:
    yaml_tag = '!vault'

    def __init__(self, s):
        self._s = s

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        return cls(node.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._s)


data = yaml.load(file_in)
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'level1': {'bootstrap': {'user': 'admin', 'admin_user': 'yes', 'admin_password': '$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256\n23423423423423423423423423423443336133616235373030363166616533396264363132323038\n31393636333735316430633062326638616665383865643453453453453453453453453453453465\n34333265303537643831376238366437336265363134396632613931376265623338346464663964\n3932653961633536360a653466383734653433313135393530323063663034373663363936306264\n30613762613164396539653462343437234234234234234234234346547567556345645763534534\n'}}}
```

However if you have many tags, this becomes tedious real fast. In that case you better discard
any tags found (the following only does tagged scalars, handling tagged sequences and mappings can
be done similarly by copying the relevant lines from composer.py and discarding the event.tag information):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

    
file_in = Path('input.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

class MyComposer(ruamel.yaml.composer.Composer):
    def compose_scalar_node(self, anchor):
        event = self.parser.get_event()
        tag = self.resolver.resolve(ruamel.yaml.nodes.ScalarNode, event.value, event.implicit)
        node = ruamel.yaml.nodes.ScalarNode(
            tag,
            event.value,
            event.start_mark,
            event.end_mark,
            style=event.style,
            comment=event.comment,
            anchor=anchor,
        )
        if anchor is not None:
            self.anchors[anchor] = node
        return node

yaml.Composer = MyComposer

data = yaml.load(file_in)
print(data)
```

which also gives:

```
{'level1': {'bootstrap': {'user': 'admin', 'admin_user': 'yes', 'admin_password': '$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256\n23423423423423423423423423423443336133616235373030363166616533396264363132323038\n31393636333735316430633062326638616665383865643453453453453453453453453453453465\n34333265303537643831376238366437336265363134396632613931376265623338346464663964\n3932653961633536360a653466383734653433313135393530323063663034373663363936306264\n30613762613164396539653462343437234234234234234234234346547567556345645763534534\n'}}}
```

Comment: in my case yaml.load takes more then 20 seconds and because we use this module dor a web application the browser times out. with C loader I could reduce load time of 3 sec.

Comment: I hope those 3 seconds are not for the snippet you presented in the question. I updated my answer with a generic "discard all tags for scalars" routine. If you need more speed, and the YAML doesn't change on every read and you are not relying on anything not supported by JSON (date-time, anchors, etc.), then consider dumping the data loaded from YAML to a JSON file (with the faster `ujson`) and loading the JSON unless the YAML file is newer than your JSON file)